# Using Angular 6, why does http.get() not retrieve my static data?

Tags: angular, https

I have a Node.js server setup on Linux running with SSL and the CORS package. I am able to access my website from Windows in Firefox with the HTTPS protocol:

```
https://<host-name>:<port>/
```

But, in my Angular code, using:

```
http.get("https://<host-name>:<port>/test/data")
```

I only get this error message `*Array.from is not a function*.`  I don't actually see the browser make the HTTPS call while viewing the developer tools screens.

If I run the server and use a local browser, everything works!

Could this be a polyfills problem, another CORS problem, or something else?

Here is part of what my service looks like:

```
...
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
...
export class ObtainData
{
    private val: any;
    private obsvbl: Observable<any>;
    private url = 'https://<host-name>:<port>/test/data';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient);

    getData(): Observable<any>
    {
        this.obsvbl = this.http.get<any>(this.url);

        this.obsvbl.subscribe((data: any) =>
                              {
                                  console.log("data is: " + data.val);
                                  // 'val' is a string contained in
                                  // a JSON structure.

                                  this.val = data;
                              },
                              err => console.log("Err is: " + err.message),
                              () => console.log("Done!"));

        return this.obsvbl;
    }
}
```

I build with this command:

```
ng build --aot --base-href=/testing-area/
```

I cannot cut/paste my entire stack trace, but I'll type as much as I can here:

```
"Err is: Array.from is not a function" (main.js:290)
"ERROR" TypeError: a[getSymbolIterator(...)] is not a function (main.js:393)
 stack trace:
 areIterablesEqual@https://<host-name>:<port>/testing-area/vendor.js:13061:9
 devModeEqual@https://<host-name>:<port>/testing-area/vendor.js:12990:9
 {more stuff}
"ERROR CONTEXT" Object(view: Object, nodeIndex: 4, nodeDef: Object, elDef: 
                       Object, elView: Object) (main.js:393)
"ERROR" TypeError: a[getSymbolIterator(...)] is not a function (main.js:393)
 stack trace:
 {same stuff}
```

Comment: please post your service as well.

Comment: If more information needs to be submitted, please let me know what else I can include.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I just upgraded my Firefox browser from version 31 to version 38.5.2.  Once I did that and reloaded my application, none of the errors (previously listed in my question) appeared.  And, my static data finally arrived as expected.